# Effect of negative statement after the conjuction 'and'

Tags: negation, conjugation

I just read the following statement,

```
100% Administrator Trust

Administrators have and will never have access to any unencrypted data.
```

I am sure that author wanted to imply that (1) Administrators do not have access to any unencrypted data, and (2) Administrators will never have access to any unencrypted data.

However, it is not clear to me how the negation after the conjunction implies also to the part before the conjunction. Is this a correct formulation given the implied meaning and if yes, why?

Comment: Yes, the sentence seems to contradict itself. *Administrators **do not** have and **never will** have access to any unencrypted data.*

Comment: The 'and' serves as the logical AND to the two phrases. You are correct in seeing the unintended contradiction.